# Change the document title when page load using jstl and javascript

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee

I am changing the document page title when page loads using below method. I am using jstl 1.0.2

```
<html>
<head></head>

<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
function updateTitle() { 
    document.title = '<c:out value="${titleName}"/>';
}

window.onload=updateTitle;    
</script>

<body>
<% if(somecondition) { %>
<c:set var="titleName" value="new title"/>
<% }else if (othercondition){ %>
<c:set var="titleName" value="other title"/>
<%}%>
</body>
</html>
```

But i am getting

```
This attribute does not support request time values.
    document.title = '<c:out value="${titleName}"/>';
```

In web.xml, I have already define `xmlns:c="urn:jsptld:http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"` and the jsp page also i have define `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>`

What other configaration i need to add in order to make above work and also i want to know whether my approach is correct too?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that nothing to do with jstl. Simply JS can do the job using -

```
document.title = "This is new Title.";
```

and then refresh if needed (manual OR using JS).

Comment: If you know title at client side, its possible using this answer. If not, you need to set  value from jsp.

Answer (score 0):

Please try by changing your taglib uri for jstl core to be:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Please note that the uri should be(notice **jsp** in uri path) http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/tld-summary.html

Answer (score 0):

You can put the conditions in javascript method to judge it.

```
<html>
<head></head>

<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
function updateTitle() { 
    if (somecondition) {
        document.title = '<c:out value="new title"/>';
    } else if(othercondition) {
        document.title = '<c:out value="other title"/>';
    }

}

window.onload=updateTitle;    
</script>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: well its just a sample code i pasted there. i am doing some other logics also based on the conditions. Problem is the value attribute in c tag is not recognized